# Browser back button is not showing changes on same page in Asp.Net page

Tags: asp.net

I have a Asp.Net application. There is one `search.aspx` page to filter the content using check boxes. I have used jQuery to filter the content in the application.When I filter through check boxes the URL remains same ie `search.aspx`.

My issue is when I click on the browser back button previous filter results are not being displayed, instead I'm returned to `Home.aspx`.

How can I navigate back and forth through the filters using the browsers forward/back buttons?

Answer (score 2):

If you're not changing the page but filtering purely in Javascript, you'll need to manually manage the browser history through Javascript. There's a new HTML5 feature designed for this (History/State APIs) and it's possible to fudge it in older browsers.

Consider using something like [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) which will do a lot of the work for you.

Fundamentally, you'll be modifying the url using, either using the area after the hash to store state (old-style) or a normal parameters (new-style)

Eg:

```
/Search.aspx#Term=Some+Term
/Search.aspx?Term=Some+Term
```

[Here's am example](http://browserstate.github.io/history.js/demo/) of the technique that uses history.js